# Strange interaction (white-on-white console) with ripgrep / less in Windows 10 Pro 1903 update

Tags: windows, command-line, colors

My OS was upgraded to Windows 10 Pro 1903 recently, and my version of `less.exe` stopped working properly in some circumstances; it shows white-on-white behavior in the Command Prompt.

This seems to occur after I have run `ripgrep`; before I run `ripgrep`, `less` works fine, but after running ripgrep, something changes in the Command Prompt color settings and I get white-on-white behavior.

This didn't happen in the previous version of Windows 10 before the update.

```
C:\>less --version
less 340
Copyright (C) 1999 Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of less under the terms
of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters,
see the file named COPYING in the less distribution.

C:\>rg --version
ripgrep 0.10.0 (rev 8a7db1a918)
-SIMD -AVX (compiled)
+SIMD +AVX (runtime)
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. [`color`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/color) fixes the colors, at least until the next time I run ripgrep.

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/FAQ.md#stop-ripgrep

> How do I stop ripgrep from messing up colors when I kill it?
>   Type in color in cmd.exe (Command Prompt) and echo -ne "\033[0m" on Unix-like systems to restore your original foreground color.
>
> In PowerShell, you can add the following code to your profile which will restore the original foreground color when Reset-ForegroundColor is called. Including the Set-Alias line will allow you to call it with simply color.
>
> ```
> function Reset-ForegroundColor {
>     $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $OrigFgColor
> }
> Set-Alias -Name color -Value Reset-ForegroundColor
> ```
>
> PR #187 fixed this, and it was later deprecated in #281. A full explanation is available [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/281#issuecomment-269093893).

Comment: Current version of Less is less-551. It was released for general use on 11 Jun 2019. The Less homepage http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/

Comment: that's great, but running current versions of GNU utilities in Windows from reputable distribution sources, without Cygwin, is difficult/impossible.

Comment: I'm about to try a newer version from GoW. In any case it looks like ripgrep is at fault, not less.

Comment: The latest GoW 0.8.0 also is less version 394. Grr.

Comment: That FAQ entry is only relevant for cases where you kill ripgrep before it completes. If ripgrep completes normally, then it should reset colors automatically. It's not quite clear what's going on in your case.

Comment: This issue occurs whether or not I kill ripgrep. (I filed the issue at https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1490) It looks like a Windows issue; the same behavior occurs with `hg` when it alters colors.